# Shopware 6: How to display product name in breadcrumbs

Tags: shopware, shopware6

We want to add the product name to the breadcrumb list when current page matches a product detail page.
Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like the product is loaded yet when the breadcrumb is rendered. We have tried using `dump()` to see what variables are available and nothing related to the product.

Where should I look in order to include the product name in our breadcrumbs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `storefront/base.html.twig`. There you will see, that currently the breadcrumb-template gets passed the context and the category. If you want to also use some product-information, you have to overwrite this block like this:

```
{% block base_breadcrumb %}
    {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/layout/breadcrumb.html.twig' with {
      context: context,
      category: page.product.seoCategory,
      product: page.product
    } only %}
{% endblock %}
```

Then you can use `product` in the breadcrumb-template.